# Python - Recursive Function does not work with len() despite the returned value being a list

Tags: python

So I want to create a recursive function that functions in a use-it or lose-it sense, where it uses an unlimited number of coins by a list, and counts the number that are needed.

So say you have: change(48, [1, 5, 10, 25, 50]) it would return 6, because it would use 25x1, 10x2 and 1x3, totalling 6 coins.

```
def change(value, L):

    if not L:
        return L

    if L[-1] > value:
        return change(value, L[:-1])

    else:
        useIt = [L[-1]] + change(value - L[-1], L)
        return useIt
```

This returns the list of the coins used, however if I return len(useIt), I get this error:

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

However, this would return the right value:

```
print(len(change(48, [1, 5, 10, 25, 50])))
```

How do I return the length of the list without doing this? And no loops please, only recursion, this is review for an exam.

Comment: Properly indent your code please.

Comment: my bad lol. Fixed

Comment: You would need to maintain a counter if you do not want to just simply do `len(change(48, [1, 5, 10, 25, 50]))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have done excellent work,  just place `1` in place of `[L[-1]]` in **else** part and return 0 in the **base case** and you are done.

```
def change(value, L):
    if not L:
        return 0

    if L[-1] > value:
        return change(value, L[:-1])
    else:
        useIt = 1 + change(value - L[-1], L)
        return useIt


print(change(48, [1, 5, 10, 25, 50]))
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks!

Comment: Mind explaining why I can't do len(useIt) if it's a type list? Would like to know. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that was list, so there was mixture of return values `int` and `list` in different levels of recursion, you are welcome `@Zach Z`.